# Find all files in first sub directories

Tags: c#, path, subdirectory

I have an application which searches in all directories behind `Documents/GameLauncher/` Like this:

```
var foundApplications = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/GameLauncher", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk") || s.EndsWith(".url"));
```

This works fine but now I only want to find all the applications in the first sub directories of this folder. Like this:

```
GameLauncher/test/test.exe <--- find this file
GameLauncher/test/test/test.exe <--- Ignore this file
GameLauncher/hello/hello.exe <--- find this file
```

I have searched around and came up with this:

```
//Search for first sub directories of path
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/GameLauncher");
IEnumerable<string> foundApplications;

//Use folders to find applications and add them to foundApplications
for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count(); i++)
{
    foundApplications += Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/GameLauncher/" + folders[i], "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk") || s.EndsWith(".url"));
}

//Ends up with error "Use of unassigned local variable 'foundApplications'" when using = instead of += in the forloop above.
foreach (var application in foundApplications){
    MessageBox.Show(application.ToString());
}
```

Does anyone have any tips to solve this problem or even a better way to find those files in the first sub directories of my GameLauncher folder?

Thanks for reading/helping.

Comment: Don't use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` when searching a sub directory, instead use `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`.  Also you might want to use the `Path.Combe` for combining paths instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: In the lower snippet, where is the variable foundApplications declared and initialized?

Comment: @AndersForsgren foundApplications is declared like this next to var folders `IEnumerable<string> foundApplications;`

Comment: Make it a `List<string>` and then use `AddRange` not `+=`.  Either that or use `Enumerable.Concat` and initialize it to `Enumerable<string>.Empty`.

Comment: @juharr gonna try that one thanks for the tip!

Comment: Exactly: it's declared there but not initialized there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the "all" option if you don't want all, simple as that.

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    @"GameLauncher");
var includedExtensions = new HashSet<string> { ".exe", ".lnk", ".url" };
var files =
    from dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
    from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir)
    let extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
    where includedExtensions.Contains(extension)
    select file;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for I tried to do a work around with a forloop and `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` but this is even better. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should be working with a list instead of an IEnumerable since it will grow dynamically.

```
var foundApplications = new List<string>();

var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/GameLauncher");

//Use folders to find applications and add them to foundApplications
for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count(); i++)
{
    foundApplications.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/GameLauncher/" + folders[i], "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk") || s.EndsWith(".url").ToList());
}

foreach (var application in foundApplications){
    MessageBox.Show(application.ToString());
}
```

Comment: They're not using an array, they're using an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @juharr ah I see he didn't have that in there when I was answering. I assumed he was using an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append one `IEnumerable` to another you need to use `Concat`.  You'll also have to initialize `foundApplications` to an empty `IEnumerable`.

```
var folderPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), 
    "GameLauncher");
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath);
IEnumerable<string> foundApplications = Enumerable<string>.Empty;

//Use folders to find applications and add them to foundApplications
foreach(var subFolder in folders)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(folderPath, subFolder);
    foundApplications.Concat(
        Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk") || s.EndsWith(".url")));
}

foreach (var application in foundApplications){
    MessageBox.Show(application.ToString());
}
```

Also I'm pretty sure you want to use `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` not `SearchOption.AllDirectories`